# netfilter speed limit

Tags: linux-kernel, netlink

I am testing netlink filter application on 1Gbit/sec network: i have user space function sending verdict to netlink socket; another user space routine performs async read of marked packets from netlink socket and some custom filter function. For the bitrates >300 Mbps i see netlink socket read errors "no buffer space available". I take it as netlink buffer overflow.
Can someone recommend an approach on how to improve netlink throughput for high speed network? My kernel version is 2.6.38.

Comment: Which function is this "no buffer space available" message being reported from?

Comment: I don't think netlink sockets are designed for high-performance packet processing.

Comment: Which function is this "no buffer space available" message being reported from?\n

Comment: Which function is this "no buffer space available" message being reported from? 
I have user space thread reading packets from netfilter:
Sock = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_FIREWALL)
while(1) {
//wait for the data to become available
select(Socket+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &Timeout);
...
//read 
int res = recvfrom(Socket, (void*)packet_buffer, MAXMSGSIZE, 0,
           (struct sockaddr *)&sockaddr, (socklen_t *)&count);

if (res <= 0) {
// ERROR: unable to receive packet message - no buffer space available

Answer (score 0):

There is socket between kernel to user space. via the socket packet upload to user space.  the socket buffer is full , so you get an error.
in c you can define the socket buffer size and increase it (this is done by netlink)